# EF Core AddIdentity method preventing Add-Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting error while trying to add migration. Looked for the problem and found that when I remove the code above, Add-Migration works fine but when I uncomment the code, getting error.
code:

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

result of command `Add-Migration v1`:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: GenericArguments[1], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type 'TRole'.
Unable to create an object of type 'DBContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

I heard that I should separate my dbcontext to 2 dbcontext, one for identity object and another for other objects. But I couldn't find any examples or good way to use 2 dbcontext on 1 database. (all models are having db-relations)

Comment: how does your dbcontext look? Are you implementing the ApplicationUser in the IdentityDbContext?

Comment: @AchoVasilev I found the problem. I didn't make changes for IdentityRole so didn't make an object for that. built a new object of type IdentityRole and replaced it's name with IdentityRole at DBContext and Startup.cs, so now problem is fixed.